# 'x' must be numeric for histogram of row of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram

I have a dataframe `df` for which I want to make a histogram of some of the rows.
I can select the rows with `df["row1",]` and I get (showing 4 of 114 columns):

```
     X3432_re  X232_fa  X212_lf  X634_fv
row1 5.1       4.3      3.7      3.7
```

However, when I try `hist(df["row1",])` I get the `'x' must be numeric` error. I tried `hist(as.vector(df["row1",]))` but got the same problem. How can I make a histogram of a row of a dataframe?

Comment: Try `hist(as.numeric(df["row1",]))`

Comment: Try `hist(t(df["row1",]))`. It will work if the values are indeed numeric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`df["row1",]` will still be a data.frame so `hist(df["row1",])` won't work by default (as `hist` requires a vector).

Now assuming all your columns can be coerced to numeric I suspect this will work since a numeric atomic vector will be created:

```
hist(as.numeric(df["row1",]))
```

Comment: Actually, it won't work even if all columns are numeric. `is.numeric` should pretty much always return `FALSE` on a data frame (or a single row of a data frame).

Comment: This works fine: `as.numeric(data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(1,2),c=c(1,2))['1',])
[1] 1 1 1`. Same for a data.frame I am currently working on with factors, integers and doubles.

Comment: No, I didn't mean your solution won't work, I mean `hist(d[1,])` won't work _even if_ all columns are numeric, which makes your first paragraph a little misleading. Clearly, if you explicitly coerce to numeric it will work fine.

Comment: That's fine, I was just clarifying that the fact that `hist(d[1,])` doesn't work doesn't automatically mean some of the columns aren't numeric, that's all.

Comment: @joran Yeah you re absolutely right. I will word it better. Thanks for this.